# Filtering by ForeignKey with a legacy model doesn't work without .pk

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a legacy database that I've set up some models to use.  The models look like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, db_column='uid')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'legacy_user'

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('my_app.UserProfile', db_column='uid')
    some_data = models.IntegerField()
    another_model = models.ForeignKey('other_app.AnotherModel', db_column='related')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'legacy_other_model'
```

When I perform this queryset:

```
my_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username='foo')
count = OtherModel.objects.filter(user=my_user).count()
```

I get SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `legacy_other_model` WHERE `legacy_other_model`.`uid` = None
```

But if I change the count query to this (note the **.pk**):

```
count = OtherModel.objects.filter(user=my_user.pk).count()
```

I get SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `legacy_other_model` WHERE `legacy_other_model`.`uid` = 12345
```

This doesn't seem to be the expected behavior, looking at: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#queries-over-related-objects

Did I set up something wrong in my models?

Comment: Just a loose guess - maybe those queries over related objects are buggy in that they assume that primary key is always `id`. In case noone answers this you might check if something like this is reported in Django bug tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I believe this is a bug in Django.

For future reference, I've reported it here:
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15164

Answer (score 0):

Suspect you might need to specify `to_field` on your OneToOne definition:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('my_app.UserProfile', db_column='uid', to_field='user')
```

Does that help?

Comment: to_field defaults to the primary key of the related model.  Specifying it doesn't help - it still puts 'None' in the SQL.